# SPRESENSEにて、attachTimerInrerrupt()とADS1115の併用時に発生するHard faultについて

Tags: spresense

下記のプログラム（一部抜粋）のように、タイマー割込み内にてads1115から電圧読取りを行いたいのですが、adc関連のタスク実行時にHard faultが発生します。

- ads1115のみの運用
- タイマー割り込みのみの運用
- タイマー割り込み&割込み関数以外でのads併用

上記3つではHard faultが発生しないので、割込み関数内でads関連のライブラリ使用が問題と思われますが、原因や対策はないでしょうか？現状、ads1115のライブラリは「ADS1115_WE」を使用しております。

【プログラム（一部抜粋）】

```c
#define INTERVAL 2000000
ADS1115_WE adc = ADS1115_WE(I2C_ADDRESS);
float voltage = 0.0;
int cnt = 0;
...

unsigned int callback_func() {
  Serial.println(adc.getResult_V());
  cnt=cnt+1;
  if(cnt==DATA_LEN)
  {
    detachTimerInterrupt();
  }
  
  return INTERVAL;
}

setup(){
  ...
  adc.setCompareChannels(ADS1115_COMP_0_GND);
  attachTimerInterrupt(callback_func, INTERVAL);
  ...
}
```

【エラー内容】

```
up_hardfault: PANIC!!! Hard fault: 40000000
up_assert: Assertion failed at file:armv7-m/up_hardfault.c line: 148 task: 9?
up_registerdump: R0: 000000e0 0d00a841 000000e0 0d026774 0d007f25 00000000 0d0267a0 0d0267a0
up_registerdump: R8: 0d007f41 00000000 0d0267a0 0d003cef 0d003f39 0d026774 0d003f39 0d003f39
up_registerdump: xPSR: 0d003f67 BASEPRI: 0d0267a8 CONTROL: 00000000
up_registerdump: EXC_RETURN: 0d0213a5
up_dumpstate: sp:     0d0267a8
up_dumpstate: IRQ stack:
up_dumpstate:   base: 0d026800
up_dumpstate:   size: 00000800
up_dumpstate:   used: 00000148
up_stackdump: 0d0267a0: 0d003f39 0d003dab 0d0267a8 00000000 0d003cef 0d003f39 0d026774 0d003f39
up_stackdump: 0d0267c0: 0d003f39 0d0267d0 0d003fcf 00000003 0d003f39 0d003fd7 0d003fb5 0d00da4b
up_stackdump: 0d0267e0: 000000e0 0d00a841 000000e0 0d026774 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f67
up_dumpstate: sp:     0d00a841
up_dumpstate: User stack:
up_dumpstate:   base: 0d003f39
up_dumpstate:   size: 0d003f39
up_dumpstate:   used: 0d003f3c
up_dumpstate: ERROR: Stack pointer is not within the allocated stack
up_stackdump: 00000000: 0d02963c 0d003931 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d033f39 05cfbb60
up_stackdump: 00000020: 00000014 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39
up_stackdump: 00000040: 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39
up_stackdump: 00000060: 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39
up_stackdump: 00000080: 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39
up_stackdump: 000000a0: 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39
up_stackdump: 000000c0: 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39
up_stackdump: 000000e0: 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39
up_stackdump: 00000100: 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39
up_stackdump: 00000120: 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39
up_stackdump: 00000140: 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39
up_stackdump: 00000160: 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39 0d003f39
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

公式マニュアルをみると、`attachTimerInterrupt()`から登録する関数は「割り込みハンドラから呼ばれるため、呼び出し可能な API には制限があります」とあるので、組み込みソフトウェアによくある制限事項でHardFaultが発生しているのだと思います。
https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_developer_guide_ja.html#_attachtimerinterrupt

対策について、Arduinoでよく見掛ける方法ですが、グローバル変数にフラグを用意して、`callback_func()`関数ではフラグをセットするだけにして、`loop()`の中でそのフラグをみてフラグが立っているときだけadc関連の処理を行った後にフラグをクリアする、という方法があります。

もう少し高度(?)な方法としては、pthreadやセマフォといったOS機能を使って、タイマースレッドで処理を行うという手もあります。参考になるコードを貼りつけておきます。タイマースレッドを作成して、タイマーが発火するたびにそのスレッドにイベントを送っています。

```c
#define INTERVAL 2000000
ADS1115_WE adc = ADS1115_WE(I2C_ADDRESS);
float voltage = 0.0;
int cnt = 0;
...

sem_t g_sem_event; // 同期セマフォ

// タイマースレッド
static int timer_thread(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  while (1) {
    sem_wait(&g_sem_event); // タイマーイベント待ち

    Serial.println(adc.getResult_V());
    cnt=cnt+1;
    if(cnt==DATA_LEN)
    {
      detachTimerInterrupt();
    }
  }
}

unsigned int callback_func()
{
  sem_post(&g_sem_event); // タイマーイベント発行

  return INTERVAL;
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // 同期セマフォ作成
  sem_init(&g_sem_event, 0, 0);

  // タイマースレッド作成
  struct sched_param param;
  pthread_t pid;
  pthread_attr_t attr;

  pthread_attr_init(&attr);
  attr.stacksize = 8192;
  param.sched_priority = 200;
  pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &param);

  pthread_create(&pid, &attr, (pthread_startroutine_t)timer_thread, NULL);
  pthread_setname_np(pid, "timer_thread");

  ...
  adc.setCompareChannels(ADS1115_COMP_0_GND);
  attachTimerInterrupt(callback_func, INTERVAL);
  ...
}

void loop()
{
}
```